# How to access custom ApplicationUser properties from view in ASP.net core 6?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, model-view-controller, asp.net-identity

I have just added custom properties to the ApplicationUser class, which has worked and the database is now storing those properties. However, I am not sure how to display these properties on the MVC view.

This is my application user class:

```
using System;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity;

namespace IssueTracker.Areas.Identity.Data
{
    public class ApplicationUser : IdentityUser
    {
        public String? FirstName { get; set; }

        public String? LastName { get; set; }

        public int? RoleNumber { get; set; }

    }
}
```

Originally, my _LoginPartial.cshtml references the Identity name through this line:

```
@User.Identity?.Name
```

How can I change this to show the FirstName property? Additionally, how can I change this so that I can access all 3 properties from the ApplicationUser class on any view or partial view?

I have tried looking at other posts, but most are outdated and did not work.
Thank you! I am new to MVC, so forgive me if my question is simple or if I come across as a starter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can inject `UserManager<T>` into your view, Then get the value. refer to this simple demo:

```
@inject  UserManager<ApplicationUser> userManager;


<h2>
@foreach (var item in userManager.Users)
  {
     //Then you can get the value of these proerties.
      @item.FirstName
      @items.LastName 
      @items.RoleNumber
      
  }
</h2>
```

Mode details you can refer to [Dependency injection into views in ASP.NET Core](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/views/dependency-injection?view=aspnetcore-6.0).

If you want to show the properties of the currently logged in user, You can refer to this demo:

Add Httpcontext in `program.cs`:

`builder.Services.AddHttpContextAccessor();`

In View:

```
@using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http;

@inject  UserManager<AppUser> userManager;
@inject IHttpContextAccessor _context;

@{
   var user =await userManager.GetUserAsync(_context.HttpContext.User);
}

   

  <h1>
      @user.FirstName 
      @user.LastName
      //......
  </h1>
```